# Accessibility of private nested classes

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

I have a class like

```
@SomeAnnotation(Outer.Inner.class)
enum Outer {
    A, B, C;
    private static class Inner {...}
}
```

which works fine in Eclipse, but `javac` complains about private access. Which compiler is right?

According to what I know, all access restrictions get ignored as long as the access occurs in the same source file.

Comment: Do you get the same error message with `Outer.Innner.class`?

Comment: My bad, it must be `Outer.Innner.class`, otherwise it doesn't get found (both using Eclipse and javac).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessibility in the class declaration is different than from within the class - no symbols in the declaration can refer to private members. This is because the information given by the declaration must inherently be available to at least the rest of the package.

For example, consider a package-private class `Outer`:

```
class Outer<T extends Outer.Inner> {

   private static class Inner { }
}
```

The above is invalid because other members of the package would not have access to `Inner`, even though they must be able to access `Outer` and know what it is via its declaration. Similar logic can be applied to your situation.

I'm not sure why Eclipse allowed it, but I would say javac is correct and NetBeans seems to agree.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, I must use `Outer.Inner`, otherwise it doesn't work. I've just fixed my question. The problem is the accessibility in `javac` as stated before.

Comment: The only way to make this non-CW would be to delete it and post a new answer.  Sorry, even mods can't undo CW.

Comment: @Bill - Oh okay, I thought I read on meta this was possible. Don't worry about it and sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @Kublai: No worries.  If you can find it on Meta, I'd love to know.  :)

Comment: @Bill - I had (mis?)read this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status/83373#83373

Comment: @Kublai: Nope, you were right.  I just didn't know about this now 6 month old feature and looked for it in entirely the wrong place when you first flagged for it.  Thanks for pointing out that Meta post, or who knows how long I would have gone without seeing it!

Comment: @Kublai Khan: I don't get the part "they must be able to access `Outer`". Why must they? Wouldn't the same argument apply to *all classes* if `Outer` was `public`?

Comment: @maaartinus - Exactly. Note that class-level access modifiers are limited to public and package-private (no modifier). Classes cannot be private since this doesn't make sense - they must at least be visible to other package members, and this means anything in their declaration must also have that visibility. Otherwise, to another package member, `Outer` would look like it had `@SomeAnnotation(ITSASECRET.class)` - it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Kublai Khan: But I can make `Outer` public and `Outer.Inner` package-private, it works fine also with `javac`.

Comment: @maaartinus - Hmm, and it looks like only a warning rather than an error if applied to my example: `Exporting non-public type through public API`. I'm not sure anymore - there may be differences between how annotations are compiled from the other parts of a class declaration, but I don't know enough about them. I think class-level visibility is a part of it though. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I recall some vague security incident resulting from the mechanism by which all within the same source file works.

It's entirely possible that it no longer works in newer versions of java.